# Any good book on domain driven design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm trying to find a good, simple introduction to domain driven design, but that is proving to be difficult.

The books I have looked at all share the same problems.

1. They are massive 300+ pages. I really wish this practice would change with computer books.
2. They shine in chapter 1, explaining the introductory and basic concepts. Then when it comes down to getting into the material they blaze through the advanced concepts with poor examples and little explanation, then jump to the next concept.

Am I asking too much when I ask is there a book for domain driven design under 300 pages that progresses at a constant pace?

I hate it when books spend so much time on the introductory concepts, yet don't bother explaining the more advanced stuff.

- Update
- The reason I want a sub 300 page book is because those 500+ page monsters have a lot of fluff in them and can't seem to get to the point (or skip it altogether).

Comment: What's wrong with the Eric Evans book on DDD? Is it just too long for your taste?

Comment: Too long for many tastes.  It's an excellent book, but I thought he could have used a better editor.  It dragged in the middle.  When I told him this he smiled and agreed.

Comment: You're asking for a short book, yet it must detail advanced concepts?

Comment: I'm asking for a book under 300 pages that can explain advanced concepts in plain english with decent examples. I know that's asking for a lot.

Comment: Read Evans book. Twice or more. Otherwise - You are just wasting time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one - available online at InfoQ. On the plus side, it's free. On the downside, it might be too basic for you. If you want an introduction though, surely it's the basic concepts that you want to get to grips with first before delving into the advanced topics?

[Domain Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly) - 104 pages.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at this one, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's also another free download, [DDD Step by Step](http://thinkddd.com/assets/2/Domain_Driven_Design_-_Step_by_Step.pdf) - a *really* short introduction to DDD, only 34 pages.
(and the corresponding webpage [Think DDD](http://thinkddd.com/))